# Customising Mui pagination to dots instead of numbers

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, pagination

Does anyone know if it is possible to customise Mui Pagination component to show dots instead of numbers?
Thanks

Here is the desired look:
[image: dot_pagination]

I tried adding an icon in `renderItem` prop in a few different ways but to no avail.